# webserver displaying wrong layout

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Ive recently deployed my asp.net mvc application.

functions work like they are suppose to but I have a design problem.

I am using bootstrap

I have a few pages on the site and some pages needed to be a little bit bigger so I have up to 20 colmns on two pages and a maximum of 12 columns on another page.

I used two seperate layouts to make this work where one loads the bootstrap file with 12 columns and  the ther layuout lods the file with 20 columns.

bundle:

12 columns (bootstrap.min)

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/energy/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-select.css",
                 "~/Content/octicons.css",
                  "~/Content/css/select2.css",
                  "~/Content/Automation.css"));
```

20 columns (bootstrap)

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/energyTwo/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-select.css",
                 "~/Content/octicons.css",
                  "~/Content/css/select2.css",
                  "~/Content/Automation.css"));
```

layout1:

```
@Styles.Render("~/energy/css")
```

layout2:

```
@Styles.Render("~/energyTwo/css")
```

This workes localy but on the webserver for some reason the file with bootstrap -12 columns always get loaded and not the one with 20 columns. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the site itself it's almost impossible to know for sure. Are you seeing any errors in the console? Any files not loadng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your bootstrap files differently:

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/energy/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-select.css",
                 "~/Content/octicons.css",
                  "~/Content/css/select2.css",
                  "~/Content/Automation.css"));


bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/energyTwo/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.modified.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-select.css",
                 "~/Content/octicons.css",
                  "~/Content/css/select2.css",
                  "~/Content/Automation.css"));
```

And always point the full versions of css files to bundles as it heavily relies on naming conventions.

Bundling and Minification will use the files you point for debugging purposes and generate minified versions for release. For example, `energy` bundle will generate `bootstrap.min.css` for `Release` configuration and use `bootstrap.css` for `Debug` configuration.

Comment: You are a hero! ive been at this for the better part of the day! thank you!